Is this tongue-twister grammatical?
The tongue-twister goes:

Can a can of canned cans can a canned can of cans, if a can of canned cans can can a canned can of cans? Yes, a can of canned cans can can a canned can of cans, if a canned can of cans can can a canned can of cans.

It plays on the multiple-meaning word can, which variously means could, a cylindrical tin container, and to be in a cylindrical tin container (canned).
A less confusing version would be:

Can a tin can, which contains contained tin cans, contain a tin can, which contains smaller tin cans, if they could?

Of course it could, because the question already claimed that it could do that.

Given that you can make sense of it, what makes you think it's not grammatically correct?

I commonly make little grammar mistakes that I couldn't spot myself, so I thought that others may be able to do so. Plus, my country is foreign, and I especially live in the countrysides, so I have limited access to people who's able to help me.

Also "to put into a cylindrical metal container," or even, by extension, into a glass jar.

It's grammatical but nonsensical.

More well known, but not really a tongue twister: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

Given the original:

Can a can of canned cans can a canned can of cans, if a can of canned cans
can can a canned can of cans? Yes, a can of canned cans can can a canned
can of cans, if a canned can of cans can can a canned can of cans.

To figure out whether this is grammatical, all you have to do is disentangle all the many uses of can and its inflections by applying a series of lexical substitutions using alternate words with similar meaning.
I’ll do this in five steps, although the last one isn’t strictly necessary.

modal verb can = present tense of modal verb could, periphrastic to be able to

Could a can of canned cans can a canned can of cans, if a can of canned cans
could can a canned can of cans? Yes, a can of canned cans could can a canned
can of cans, if a canned can of cans could can a canned can of cans.


noun: a can = a tin, a container, an enclosure, a package

Could a container of canned containers can a canned container of containers, if a container of canned containers
could can a canned container of containers? Yes, a container of canned containers could can a canned
container of containers, if a canned container of containers could can a canned container of containers.


adjective canned = tinned, packaged, preserved

Could a container of packaged containers can a packaged container of containers, if a container of packaged containers
could can a packaged container of containers? Yes, a container of packaged containers could can a packaged
container of containers, if a canned container of containers could can a packaged container of containers.


lexical verb to can = to preserve OR to contain, package, enclose

Could a container of packaged containers enclose a packaged container of containers, if a container of packaged containers
could enclose a packaged container of containers? Yes, a container of packaged containers could enclose a packaged
container of containers, if a packaged container of containers could enclose a packaged container of containers.


modal verb can/could > periphrastic to be able to

Is a container of packaged containers able to enclose a packaged container of containers, if a container of packaged containers
is able to enclose a packaged container of containers? Yes, a container of packaged containers is able to enclose a packaged
container of containers, if a packaged container of containers is able to enclose a packaged container of containers.



That shows you that the original was in fact grammatical. That doesn’t mean it’s a particularly interesting formulation by any means.
It’s really just a variation on several other existing but equally nonsensical word-plays, as though it were a blend of How much wood could a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? on the one hand and Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo on the other.

The lexical verb can needs an agent (e.g. a person, a machine). The can cannot can things.

@TinfoilHat Interesting perspective. To me that feels overspecified, or at least over-finicky, for the task at hand, but you could be right. I guess I was envisioning some mad, animated riff on Disney's classic Fantasia   –  The Sorcerer's Apprentice, where any manner of otherwise inanimate things become fantastically animated. :) I wasn't imagining some sort of middle voice like books that read well or wine that drinks well.

Seems like something that could be found in a 1940s Looney Toons episode...

The example is grammatically correct.
In the example, the second sentence is basically a repetition of the first.
The solution is to substitute the noun, verb and adjective for completely different noun, verb and adjective that have the same form:
Thus:

Can a can of canned cans can a canned can of cans, if a can of canned cans can can a canned can of cans? Yes, a can of canned cans can can a canned can of cans, if a canned can of cans can can a canned can of cans.

becomes
[Question]. Will a box of large boxes hide a large box of boxes, if a box of large boxes will hide a large box of boxes? [Answer] Yes, a box of large boxes will hide a large box of boxes, if a large box can hide a large box of boxes.
This can be further simplified by pronouns:
Will these hide those, if those will hide similar ones? Yes, these will hide those, if those will hide similar ones.
